# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key, mysql-error-1062

So, my professor gave me tables to insert it in a database but when I execute his code, MySQL is constantly giving the Error Code: 1062.
Here is the conflict tables and the inserts:

**TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE FABRICANTES(
COD_FABRICANTE integer NOT NULL,
NOMBRE         VARCHAR(15), 
PAIS           VARCHAR(15),
primary key (cod_fabricante)
);

CREATE TABLE ARTICULOS(
ARTICULO       VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
COD_FABRICANTE integer NOT NULL,
PESO           integer NOT NULL ,
CATEGORIA      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRECIO_VENTA   integer,
PRECIO_COSTO   integer,
EXISTENCIAS    integer,
primary key (articulo,cod_fabricante),
foreign key (cod_fabricante) references Fabricantes(cod_fabricante)
);
```

**INSERT INTO:**

```
INSERT INTO FABRICANTES VALUES(10,'CALVO', 'ESPAÑA');
INSERT INTO FABRICANTES VALUES(15,'LU', 'BELGICA');
INSERT INTO FABRICANTES VALUES(20,'BARILLA', 'ITALIA');
INSERT INTO FABRICANTES VALUES(25,'GALLO', 'ESPAÑA');
INSERT INTO FABRICANTES VALUES(30,'PRESIDENT', 'FRANCIA');

INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Macarrones',20, 1, 'Primera',100,98,120);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 2, 'Primera',120,100,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 1, 'Segunda',99,50,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Macarrones',20, 1, 'Tercera',80,50,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Atún',10, 3, 'Primera',200,150,220);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Atún',10, 3, 'Segunda',150,100,220);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Atún',10, 3, 'Tercera',100,50,220);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Sardinillas',10, 1,'Primera',250,200,200);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Sardinillas',10, 1,'Segunda',200,160,200);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Sardinillas',10, 1,'Tercera',100,150,220);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Mejillones',10, 1, 'Tercera',90,50,200);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Mejillones',10, 1, 'Primera',200,150,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Macarrones',25, 1, 'Primera',90,68,150);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',25, 1, 'Primera',100,90,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Fideos',25, 1, 'Segunda',75,50,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Fideos',25, 1, 'Primera',100,80,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Galletas Cuadradas',15, 1, 'Primera',100,80,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Galletas Cuadradas',15, 1, 'Segunda',70,50,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Galletas Cuadradas',15, 1, 'Tercera',50,40,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Barquillos',15, 1, 'Primera',100,80,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Barquillos',15, 1, 'Segunda',100,80,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Canutillos',15, 2, 'Primera',170,150,110);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Canutillos',15, 2, 'Segunda',120,150,110);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche entera',30, 1, 'Primera',110,100,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche desnat.',30, 1, 'Primera',120,100,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche semi.',30, 1, 'Primera',130,110,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche entera',30, 2, 'Primera',210,200,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche desnat.',30, 2, 'Primera',220,200,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Leche semi.',30, 2, 'Primera',230,210,300);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Mantequilla',30, 1, 'Primera',510,400,200);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Mantequilla',30, 1, 'Segunda',450,340,200);
```

***The ERROR:***

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'Macarrones-20' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

If I delete that row gives me the same error but with 'Tallarines-20'

Sorry if there is any spell mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Was it a problem with my answer, or why did you unaccept it?

Comment: @JonasPetersson DenisSpalenza beat you to it...

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to insert two rows with the same primary key.

```
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 2, 'Primera',120,100,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 1, 'Segunda',99,50,100);
```

You would probably need to add `CATEGORIA` to your primary key for table `ARTICULOS` because you are trying to insert multiple rows with the same primary key multiple times.

```
primary key (articulo,cod_fabricante, categoria)
```

Comment: This can also happen if you are trying to set as primary key a column that contains duplicate (my case).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrYLYV7WSHM                                                     Should not be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

7th and 8th `INSERT` rows are equal. You can not enter more than one row with the same primary key. Note that your primary key is the set: `(articulate, cod_fabricante)`, so any line with the same `articulate` and `cod_fabricante` will generate Error 1062.

```
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 2, 'Primera',120,100,100);
INSERT INTO ARTICULOS VALUES ('Tallarines',20, 1, 'Segunda',99,50,100);
```

Remove one of the lines or change the primary key of one of them.

Comment: You can change primary key like Jonas said: `primary key (articulo,cod_fabricante, categoria)`

Answer (score 1):

This error code 1062 is because of the duplicate entry. You are trying to insert a value which is already exists in the primary key field. Recently, I solved this issue by adding auto_increment to primary key field. I followed the fix provided in this post [how to solve mysql error code : 1062 duplicate entry?](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/how-to-solve-mysql-error-code-1062.html) it worked for me. Help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying to set a column as the primary key. I just deleted the column and recreated it which allowed me to assign it as the primary key. This also resolves the # 1075 error where it requires an auto increment column to be a key (if you try to set the column for auto increment).

Answer (score 0):

You have error of duplicate key in second table ARTICULOS.
you have primary key with combination of two columns (articulo,cod_fabricante).

So all rows are uniquely defined in combination of these columns. remove duplicate rows from second table or change primary key instead.